# Python: keep track of elements moving within a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list of objects:

```
MyList = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
```

During the execution of the code, these objects might be moved of position. This movement usually happens one-by-one, so (for example) the item "D" might be moved right after "A". The list becomes, hence, as follows:

```
MyList = [A, D, B, C, E, F, G]
```

What I would like to know is if there's a method (I've already tried to build an algorithm but I would like to make the code shorter) to keep track of the elements over the list, so that I can use the indexes to recover them into the same list when I need to use them (the other parts of the code cannot be touched, otherwise I would implement this in the moving loops themselves). To explain better, I would like to know if it's possible to make something like this:

```
#ORIGINARY LIST
MyList = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
Current_Indexes= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

#ITERATION THAT MOVES D RIGHT AFTER A
MyList = [A, D, B, C, E, F, G]
Current_Index_Mapping = [0,3,1,2,4,5,6] #method or built-in function???
```

I have in mind something algorithmically, like creating a list at the beginning of the code like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(MyList)):
    Current_Index_Mapping.append((i,MyList[i]))
```

and then extracting the tuples to update the Current_Index_Mapping list. However I'm pretty new to Python programming and I don't know lot of methods and built-in functions, so I was wondering: does anyone have a better idea to get the same result?

Comment: check out python builtin `enumerate`

Comment: @wim, The [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) builtin seems to be the one I'm looking for. However it's not really clear in my mind how I can recover the indexes depending on the objects. What I need is basically to get back some elements in a few loops depending on their characteristics, that's why I need to keep track of their positions within the list. The original code (that I didn't write and I cannot change) is veryfing conditions on the elements assuming their positions didn't change, but this is not the case anymore...

Comment: BTW, if A,B,C, etc. are actually objects (i.e. not immutable strings, tuples, or ints), you might be able to get by with just making a shallow copy of the list. Then you could pass this copy to the downstream function, for it to rearrange as it likes. Since it's a shallow copy, changes made to the objects will be reflected in the original list too (both hold references to the same object), but the index in the original list won't move.

Comment: @CorleyBrigmanm thanks for your answer. I'm still having a problem though. This is what I did: `copy = self.MyList[:]`, and it stores well. Then I keep on working on the original list, `MyList`, and changes are done in both lists (copy and original). After that, though, I do `self.MyList = copy` but after this command is executed the list `MyList` is still the same :/

Comment: don't use copy - it's not reserved, but normally it points to `from copy import copy`, which is a function. what do you mean they are 'the same'? if you don't modify the _order_ of objects in either list, even though they aren't exactly the same list, they are identical. if you are modifying order in one list, and not seeing MyList update, that is a little weird.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman sorry for my late reply. The reason why I'm trying to keep a copy of the list is because I want it to be with the same objects but with different order. The objects order within the list will be changed during execution, as well as for the object themselves. I would like to "restore" the old list, or better, just the order of the elements, by keeping a copy before starting mixing up. But the problem is that although I'm able to both make a copy and modify the original list, when I try to set `oldList = copyOfList` it just doesn't work :/

Comment: @CorleyBrigman p.s.: I'm not using "copy", I'm giving another name but here I changed it just to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 6):

Map the *id* of objects to original indice:

```
>>> a, b, c, d, e, f, g = [object() for i in range(7)]
>>> lst = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]

>>> objid_to_idx = {id(obj): idx for idx, obj in enumerate(lst)} # <---
# {
#     id(a): 0,
#     id(b): 1,
#     ...
#     id(g): 6,
# }

>>> [objid_to_idx[id(obj)] for obj in lst]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

>>> lst = [a, d, b, c, e, f, g]
>>> [objid_to_idx[id(obj)] for obj in lst]
[0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]

>>> lst = [a, d, b, a, c, e, e, f, g]
>>> [objid_to_idx[id(obj)] for obj in lst]
[0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```

used [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to build mapping.

Comment: +1 for a good, non-invasive idea, but if it is possible to append the indices into the original list and still have it quack enough like a duck to be processed by the mysterious untouchable code, then that would be a preferable solution

Comment: @wim, Thank you for the comment, but I don't fully understand your comment. Do you mean something like `a.index = 0`?

Comment: What I meant was to stick the original indices onto the objects in some way (a way that is invisible to the code which moves things around), so that they get carried around with whatever operations happen.  This would prevent having to lookup again afterwards.

Comment: @falsetru thanks! Suppose I'd like to restore the original positioning of the list by using a static list that I get saved with `objid_to_idx = {id(obj): idx for idx, obj in enumerate(lst)} `. I simply want the list (in whatever mixed up status is at a certain moment) to re-sort itself according to what is written in the `objid_to_idx` list. How could I do that? (Sorry I'm really new to Python and the only things coming to mind are horrible and expensive loops)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, Try `sorted(lst, key=lambda obj: objid_to_idx[id(obj)])`. (`lst` here is manipulated list of objects)

Comment: @falsetru for some reasons it doesn't work for me. I mean, it works fine but not in my case. When I define the list `objid_to_idx` I get this result when I print the dictionary: `[0, 7, 2, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]`. After the list manipulation, the same print gives me this: `[0, 7, 5, 4, 2, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]`. When I execute your sorting, this is what I get: `[0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]`. That is definitely sorted, but it's not like the first print (and instead this is what I wanted to get). What'd you suggest?

Comment: @falsetru Let me explain better, what I mean is that for every loop (because this manipulation happens in a for loop) I would like to start with the list as the first print, then having the list as in the second print and at the end of the loop getting back the list sorted as it was in the first print and not in the third.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, Sorry. I don't understand your comment. BTW, `objid_to_idx` should be a dictionary.

Comment: @falsetru, sorry, I'll try to be shorter. The list I'm manipulating is always the same, and is passing through a loop that changes it everytime. At the first loop, the list has the following structure: `[0, 7, 2, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. After I make the manipulations (still in the first loop), the structure changes to `[0, 7, 5, 4, 2, 6, 6, 7]`. At the end of this same loop, I would like to restore the structure of the list to `[0, 7, 2, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. However, if I apply the sort method, I get (obviously) this result: `[0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7]`.

Comment: Please note that the result I would like to get is different from the one I get. While the last list is indeed sorted by index (from 0 to 7), it's not the same than the original list that I would like to have, that has the structure as shown in the very first list of my last comment. Do you know how I could get the list with the structure **not sorted by index but just the same of the objid_to_idx list**?

Comment: @falsetru yes, it is a dictionary, but what I printed is the result of this instruction: `[objid_to_idx[id(obj)] for obj in lst]`. The dictionary is too huge to be printed here, sorry about that.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, How about keep the (shallow) copy of original list? `copy = lst[:]`. Then restore it for recovery afterward: `lst = copy`

Comment: @falsetru I had thought about it, but my doubt is: being there are two of these objects that are dinamically re-instantiated (so they change their content according to what moves into the code), I think the changes wouldn't be registered :/

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, `copy[0] is lst[0]`. means .. both reference same objects. If you mean `lst[idx] = new_object`-like modification, my solution will not work for you.

Comment: @falsetru I'm still having a problem though. This is what I did: `copy = self.MyList[:]`, and it stores well. Then I keep on working on the original list, `MyList`, and changes are done in both lists (copy and original). After that, though, I do `self.MyList = copy` but after this command is executed the list `MyList` is still the same :/

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, Do not change `copy`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a solution is to subclass `list`?

```
class mylist(list):
    def append(self, a):
        print('Append %s' % a)
        list.append(self, a)


l = mylist()
l.append(42)
print(l)
```

Gives the output:

```
[~]% python a.py
Append 42
[42]
```

Obviously, you may need to extend more methods, such as `insert()`, but the basic concept should be clear.

Comment: i don't know why this was -1. this is definitely one way to do it - you end up with something that quacks like a list to anyone expecting one, but tracks the ids internally on any modification.

Comment: Thank you Corley :-) One advantage of using this, is that it's more memory efficient with (very) large lists, since you don't need a copy of the original...

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
def delegate_original_specials(specials):
    specialnames = ['__%s__'%s for s in specials.split()]
    def wrapit(cls, method):
        return lambda self, *args, **kwargs: getattr(self._original, method)(*args, **kwargs) 
    def dowrap(cls):
        for n in specialnames:
            setattr(cls, n,
                wrapit(cls, n))
        return cls
    return dowrap

@delegate_original_specials('getitem setitem iter add sub mul div repr str len')
class TrackedObject(object):
    __slots__ = ['_original', '_original_id']
    __original_names__ = ['_original', '_original_id']
    def __init__(self, original, originalid):
        self._original = original
        self._original_id = originalid

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self.__original_names__:
            return object.__getattr__(self, key)
        else:
            return getattr(self._original, key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.__original_names__:
            return object.__setattr__(self, key, value)
        else:
            return getattr(self._original, key, value)
```

The idea here being that instead of wrapping the *list*, you wrap the *object*, such that you can assign it an id of your choice that sticks to the object.

Example usage in your case:

```
l1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', [1,2,3], 'F']
l2 = [TrackedObject(x, index) for index, x in enumerate(l1)]

# Each item quacks like strings
print l2
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
len(l2[3])
1
l2[3].lower()
'd'
l2[4][1:]
[2,3]

# But they are tracked
l2[4]._original_id

l3 = l2[4:]
print l3
[[1, 2, 3], 'F']
l3[0]._original_id
4
```

etc. You may need to add to the list of specials that are delegated, but that should get you started.